# Why are my CSS centring styles being ignored?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML & CSS:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
html {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.mainContainer {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
.mainpagetitleContainer {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.mainpagetitle {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.mainpagetitleContainer > .subtitle {
  color: #333;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="mainpagetitleContainer">
    <div class="mainpagetitle">
      Text.
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle">
      Text.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am attempting to centre my divs as outlined in [this answer to Horizontally center a div in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/2422013), however my divs seem intent on being stuck to the left-hand side of the page rather than the centre.

The idea is to have a background and a central column to the page, like so:

[image]

I tried messing with `margin: 0px auto;` to no effect.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center divs horizontally using margin: 0 auto, you should use position relative on container and on inner divs.

Try something like this:

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.mainContainer {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
.mainpagetitleContainer {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.mainpagetitle {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.mainpagetitleContainer > .subtitle {
  color: #333;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

To understand more about layout in CSS, I recommend reading this site: http://learnlayout.com/toc.html

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of absolute positioning.

Using `position: absolute` on `html` makes it shrink-to-fit. Since `.maincontainer` is out-of-flow, `body` will be 0px wide. Then centering makes no sense.

And just adding `auto` margins won't center an absolutely positioned element. You would also need `left: 0` and `right: 0`.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.mainContainer {
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}
.mainpagetitleContainer {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.mainpagetitle {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.mainpagetitleContainer > .subtitle {
  color: #333;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="mainpagetitleContainer">
    <div class="mainpagetitle">
      Text.
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle">
      Text.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `position: absolute` keeps my site design together on screen resolutions other than my primary monitor is running, so no, not a good idea. I'm also not competent enough in CSS to do media queries either.

Comment: @cybermonkey Exactly. Why are you using `position: absolute`, then?

Comment: there's absolutely nothing wrong with this answer. `margin` and `position:absolute` are like oil and water.

Comment: @xandercoded I must have been downvoted by `position: absolute` fanatics or something. It's incomprehensible.